# Java stream find value by key if exists

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm having simple DataStructure

```
public class DataStructure {
    private String key;
    private String value;
    //get, set
}
```

And I need to return value from `List' based on key and I want to do it Java8 way, with streams. I think code speaks for himself:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      List<DataStructure> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
      dataList.add(new DataStructure("first", "123"));
      dataList.add(new DataStructure("second", "456"));

        System.out.println(findValueOldSchool(dataList, "third")); //works ok
        System.out.println(findValueStream(dataList, "third")); //throws NoSuchElementException
    }

    static String findValueOldSchool(List<DataStructure> list, String key) {
        for (DataStructure ds : list) {
            if (key.equals(ds.getKey())) {
                return ds.getValue();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    static String findValueStream(List<DataStructure> list, String key) {
        return list.stream()
                .filter(ds -> key.equals(ds.getKey()))
                .findFirst()
                .get().getValue();
    }
}
```

How can I modify `findValueStream()` to not throw NoSuchValueException while I search for non existing key? I don't want to return `Optional<String>` because this method is already used in a lot of places in project. And, ofcourse I'v tried `map`, `ifPresent`, `anyMatch`, just can't find the right way to do it.

Comment: `.findFirst().orElse(null)`

Comment: You return a function with nullable - you will lose the benefits Optional<T>. I would do return type Optional<?>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shall use [`Stream.findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst()) with an [`Optional.orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) like :

```
static String findValueStream(List<DataStructure> list, String key) {
    return list.stream() // initial Stream<DataStructure>
            .filter(ds -> key.equals(ds.getKey())) // filtered Stream<DataStructure>
            .map(DataStructure::getValue) // mapped Stream<String>
            .findFirst() // first Optional<String>
            .orElse(null); // or else return 'null'
}
```

***Note***: The above uses the [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) to map the stream of `DataStructure` to a corresponding stream of `value`.

Answer (score 2):

use `orElse` to return a default value if the Optional has an empty state:

This also means you'll need to map to `DataStructure::getValue` first like so:

```
return list.stream()
           .filter(ds -> key.equals(ds.getKey()))
           .findFirst()
           .map(DataStructure::getValue)
           .orElse(null);
```

just replacing `get` with `orElse` will **not** suffice:

```
 return list.stream()
            .filter(ds -> key.equals(ds.getKey()))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null)
            .getValue();
```

As this time you'll get a `NullPointerException` instead of a `NoSuchElementException` in the case of an empty optional.

Comment: there has to be `map`ping to `getValue` as well

Comment: Yes, i meant getValue as in the code shared by the OP without the stream implementation.

Comment: @shmosel agreed, I mean to say that the current solution proposed here would *have* to ensure the mapping is already done.

Comment: @nullpointer Right, made the answer more "explicit", sometimes when I post answers I just assume the missing part (if any) is self-explanatory.